# How can i create arrays from a query in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

in my data base i have a table "options" which contains options from my site like title, language etc.

i want to load all this options and store it in a array query the database.

this code works manual

```
$option=array("title" => "Site's title", "option2" => "option 2 value");
echo $option[title];
```

but when i make the query...

```
$query_options=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM options");

while($data_options = mysql_fetch_row($query_options)){

    $option=array($data_options[1] => $data_options[2]);


}

echo $option[title];
```

it doesn't work.

Hope you can help me.

Thank you

Comment: How does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_row() only allows you to access columns in your query based on the column ordering : $options[0] or $options[1].

Use mysql_fetch_array() instead. With it you can access data with $options["title"] for example. Using the column name.

See the doc at http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

PS - Don't forget to put title between quotes too!

Answer (score 0):

```
$query_options=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM options");
$array = array();

while($data_options = mysql_fetch_array($query_options)){

    $array[]["title"] = $data_options['title'];
    $array[]["value"] = $data_options['value'];

}

var_dump($array);
```

Should work. lemme know how it goes.

Also, you should know that you shouldn't use any mysql_* commands, they're becoming depreciated as they're in-secure, you should take a look here

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php

and

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysqli.php

Comment: i got this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/coccolare/site/header.php on line 9

Comment: Updated answer, try that.

Comment: i mod the syntax but not working

$array = array();

while($data_options = mysql_fetch_array($query_options)){

    $array[] = array($data_options["option_name"] => $data_options["option_value"]);
}

var_dump($array);

Result:
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["title"]=> string(8) "title site" } [1]=> array(1) { ["idioma"]=> string(2) "es" } }

Comment: Please edit it to match the answer, eg change the $array[] bit